# Copying one entire SDD drive to another larger one

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, uefi

My laptop (Dell Latitude E7250) contains a 256 GB mSATA SDD. Call this drive 1. I would like to bring the contents of this drive over to a 1TB mSATA (drive 2), so that my laptop will still boot.

Today, it has partitions so that I can boot either Debian 9 or Qubes OS 3. These are in legacy mode UEFI setting of the MBR, and booting in one or the other requires pointing the BIOS UEFI setting to one or the other. Please factor this into your answer!

The source SDD (presently, drive 1) has a MBR, an LVM partition (containing the Debian swap, /, and /home volume group) and an encrypted EXT4 for the QubesOS partition.

Both drives can not be in the computer at the same time.

However, I do have an external 2GB USB HDD (Western Digital MyPassport Ultra) to use as an intermediary. Call this Drive 3.

What is a good way to cause drive 2 to be the sole drive, so that the behavior of my laptop is indistinguishable from its present state with drive 1, using the ingredients I have listed above?

`dd` to an iso from drive 1 to drive 3, followed by dd from that iso to drive 2, for example makes sense. I do not know enough about `dd` to be sure it will get all partitions, or the MBR, etc., though.

Can someone help?

Comment: dd from one to the drive, then dd back. Then expand the partition, VG, and LVs.

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams does that get all partitions at the same time, and handle MBR stuff, too? In legacy UEFI-mode?

Comment: As long as you grab the whole drive, not just the partitions.

Comment: All right, I will try that when it comes in Tuesday. Basically, `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64K conv=noerror,sync`, followed by the reverse.

Comment: The output for the first dd will be a file on the external drive. The input for the second will be the same. And don't run it off the installed OS.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so, `dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/devSdb1/image.iso bs=64K conv=noerror,sync` followed by `dd if=/mnt/devSdb1/image.iso of=/dev/sda bs=64K conv=noerror,sync` ? Where /mnt/devSdb1 points to /dev/sdb1.

Comment: I'd use .img, since .iso has specific implications. And it would be on the mounted drive, not the device file.

Comment: :+1: I will try it. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That was easy! Worked fine.